# Derive a diffusion equation on the basis of the physical law $q=−D(n−n_0)^2n^2\frac{∂n}{∂x}+nv$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, physics, mathematical-physics

It is given that the mass flux density q of a substance in medium obeys the following physical law:

$$q=−D(n−n_0)^2n^2\frac{∂n}{∂x}+nv$$
where $n(x,t)$ is the concentration $([n]=ML−3)$ of the substance in the medium as a function of the space coordinate $x$ and time $t$, $D$ is a constant coefficient of diffusion, $n_0$ is a constant parameter of the problem and $v(x,t)$ is macroscopic velocity of the medium.

Derive a diffusion equation on the basis of the physical law.

Ive worked out that $D=M^{-5}L^{16}T$ but I'm really not confident with diffusion equations so any help towards the answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Dump this into the continuity equation,
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}=0.$$
The PDE follows from calculating the derivatives.

Comment: See I've not really been confident in doing this since I've started learning about this. Could you guide me??

Comment: Read more about the equation here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation

Comment: I tried to work it out and got: $\frac{∂n}{∂t} +\frac{∂(nv)}{∂x}  = \frac{∂}{∂x}(D(n−n_0)^2n^2\frac{∂n}{∂x})$ Is this correct??

Comment: So far. Now carry out derivatives of anything that depends on x.

Comment: The LHS is fine with me, but I am not sure about taking the derivative of the RHS. Could you help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54540/discussion-between-garserdt216-and-bernard).

Comment: Would expanding the binomial give you $Dn^2(n^2-2nn_0+n_0^2)$?

Comment: Are you there??